# Create Multiple Charts Off Pivot in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create loop that automatically outputs one table/chart per index. In this case, I only want one index out of the two below. Further, I don't want to even show the first index in the output... I want that index hidden behind the scenes...

Here's the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

table = {'Name': ["Joe", "Joe", "Joe","Jane","Jane"],
        'Stf Sch Vp Area': ["Org2","Org1","Org2","Org1","Org2"],
        'Snapshot': ["Feb 2015","Mar 2015","April 2015","Feb 2016","Feb 2016"],
        'Job Type': ["RBE","RBE","Temp","RBE","Temp"],
        'EE Count' :[1,1,1,1,1]}

df_table = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Name', 'Stf Sch Vp Area', 'EE Count', 'Snapshot','Job Type'])

df_table
```

Here's the table:

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df_table, index=['Stf Sch Vp Area', 'Snapshot'], values=['EE Count'], columns='Job Type', aggfunc= [np.sum])
```

And here's the chart:

```
pivot_table.plot.bar(figsize=[16,10], stacked=False)
```

But I don't want to show the **Org** in the table. Rather, I want to use some type of lambda/loop to automatically output each distinct Org into a new chart. Thus, I'd like an output that would automatically product two charts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So your `pivot_table()` is working, your problem is only with the `plot`?

Comment: Hi Christopher, welcome to stackoverflow.  Some may chip in to offer advice on your question but I thought it would be helpful to suggest some reading for you first.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  I would definitely suggest making your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I re-read the link you sent. I also updated the thread so hopefully this helps.

Yes, I can visualize the pivot based on the code, but I want to have individual cuts of the  "Stf Sch Vp Area" with the rest of the pivot data. There are like 80, and I don't want to write each out one by one...

Comment: "I didn't include the real data in due to data sensitivity" - so use some synthetic data, no?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks MaxU, that post was incredibly helpful. I think I got this post in a better place.